# Generating movement across bezier curve

Tags: bezier

I am making a small game which involves paths for Enemy AI. I want to use a path generated using Cubic Bezier curves, but need a formula which causes enemys to move across any curve at a constant speed. All I know is constant movement across straight paths, and generating bezier curves, but I dont know how to make both work together well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you've picked a *non-linear* curve, on which you want *linear speed*.

There's a few options, such as approximating the curve as linear geometries (like line segments or circular arcs), and then traveling across those at linear speed instead of the actual curve. Flattening the curve to walk along that is relatively straight forward:

```
lines = []
x=curve.getX(0), y=curve.getY(0), nx, ny
step=..., interval=1/step, t=step
while(t<=1) {
  nx = curve.getX(t)
  ny = curve.getY(t)
  lines.push( new line(x,y,nx,ny)
  x = nx
  y = ny
  t += interval
}
```

And done - we now have the curve, expressed as a linear approximation and we can just start moving along that, instead. Provided `step` was small enough, no one will notice.

Alternatively, you can build a look-up table as part of the drawing routine, and record the distance along the curve at that point, so you can then traverse the curve at a linear speed by binary-searching the remainder of the curve for the "next place" you need to be at. More initial work than option 1, but certainly faster once the moving starts.

```
function arcLength(t) {
  // true fact: computing the arc length of a bezier curve is not
  // a thing you want to end up implementing yourself. It's not hard,
  // but getting to a point where you undestand *why* it's not hard is
  // is certainly time consuming, and depending on how much your brain
  // is unwilling to just take maths at face value, definitely hard.
  // Use someone else's implementation, like this one:
  // https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/blob/gh-pages/lib/bezier.js#L87
}

Curve.draw = function() { 
  if (!this.curveLUT) {
    // form a LUT however you like. The following demonstration 
    // code uses something similar to the above flattening:
    for(i=0;i<LUT.length;i++) {
      t = i / (LUT.length-1)
      x = curve.getX(t)
      y = curve.getY(t)
      LUT.push({x:x, y:y, dist: arclength(t)})
    }    
  }
  this.curveLUT.foreach(point -> point.draw())
}
```

And then when we need to walk the curve at some specific speed:

```
speed = ...
currentPos = SomeLUTindex
if (currentPos < LUT.length) {
  currentDist = LUT[currentPos].dist
  nextDist = currentDist + speed
  nextPos = binarySearch(LUT.slice(currentPos), "dist", nextDist)
}
```

with:

```
binarySearch(List, property, target) {
  midIdx = (int) List.length/2
  mid = List[midIdx]
  curr = mid[property]
  if(curr === target) return midIdx
  if(curr > target) return binarySearch(List.slice(0,midIdx), property, target)
  if(curr < target) return midIdx + binarySearch(List.slice(midIdx), property, target)
}
```

This looks like it might recurse a lot, but binary searches resolve in `ceil(log₂(n))`, worst case, so even on a lookup table with 10000 points, this will find the next spot in at most 14 steps. Optimisations to the function are unwrapping it to a straight `for`/`while` loop too, and not slicing the list but checking specific intervals on it - both are a little more code, but relatively easy to implement with a little help from google and wikipedia.